# Oracle PL/SQL does not work -- bind variable not allowed

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, plsql

Oracle 12.2 PL/SQL

When running:

```
declare
    s_sql varchar2(200);
begin
    s_sql := 'dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@mylink' || '(''exec sp_get_names'')';
    execute immediate 'begin :x; end;' using in s_sql;
end;
/
```

Fails with:

```
PLS-00110: bind variable 'X' not allowed in this context
```

The procedure runs fine as

```
begin
     dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@mylink('exec sp_get_names'); 
end;
/
```

But I want to keep it dynamic.  So how (if at all) can the procedure `dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@mylink()` be executed in a dynamice fashion as in the first example?
NOTE:  It is not of any significance to understand what `dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@mylink()` does, just how to make it (or any other procedure that is called) dynamic.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a procedure as a bind variable.

You should be able to dynamically build the entire anonymous PL/SQL block and execute that.  Something like this

```
declare
  l_plsql varchar2(1000);
begin
  l_plsql := 'begin 
                dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@mylink ... 
              end;';
  execute immediate l_plsql;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare the return-code, you can even get it:

```
declare 
   s_sql varchar2(200);
   retcode nubmer;
begin
   s_sql := 'begin :retcode := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@mylink(''exec sp_get_names'') end;';
   execute immediate s_sql using out retcode;  
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked (which is what I believe Justin Cave was referring to above):

```
declare 
s_sql varchar2(200);
begin
s_sql := 'declare retcode integer; begin retcode := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@mydblink' || '(''exec sp_get_names''); end;';
execute immediate s_sql;  
end;
/
```

I was getting (misleading) errors at first (when trying Justin Cave's suggestion) because I forgot to handle the return code.